# Memory Metrics in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, caching, memory, ignite, metrics

> This is my code,

```
    c.put((long) 1,"JP");
    ClusterGroup remoteGroup = ignite.cluster().forRemotes();
    ClusterMetrics metrics = remoteGroup.metrics();
    long iniHeap = metrics.getHeapMemoryInitialized();
    long totHeap = metrics.getHeapMemoryTotal();
    long usedHeap = metrics.getHeapMemoryUsed();
    long maxHeap = metrics.getHeapMemoryMaximum();
    System.out.println("Heap Memory used " + usedHeap );
    System.out.println("Heap Memory Total " + totHeap );
    System.out.println("Heap Memory Maximum " + maxHeap );
    System.out.println("Heap Memory Initial " + iniHeap );

    for(long i=2;i<100;i++)
    {
        c.getAndPut(i, "JP");
    }

    long iniHeap1 = metrics.getHeapMemoryInitialized();
    long totHeap1 = metrics.getHeapMemoryTotal();
    long usedHeap1 = metrics.getHeapMemoryUsed();
    long maxHeap1 = metrics.getHeapMemoryMaximum();
    System.out.println("Heap Memory used " + usedHeap1 );
    System.out.println("Heap Memory Total " + totHeap1 );
    System.out.println("Heap Memory Maximum " + maxHeap1 );
    System.out.println("Heap Memory Initial " + iniHeap1 );
```

> This is my Output,

```
Heap Memory used 30410944
Heap Memory Total 4246732800
Heap Memory Maximum 4246732800
Heap Memory Initial 266338304

Heap Memory used 30410944
Heap Memory Total 4246732800
Heap Memory Maximum 4246732800
Heap Memory Initial 266338304
```

> In both cases( for 1 object and 100 object) used heap printing the same value.. How can i know this is the size of memory used by one Object and this is the size of memory used by 100 object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Apache Ignite will not store objects on heap so you should not rely on heap metrics.

Please note that 100 objects is too few to reliably observe difference in any metrics.

Comment: Then, How i should know my cache is used this much of memory on server, and this much memory free in my cache?

Comment: Ignite will print off-heap memory statistics to logs every so often, you can also use metrics/JMX.

Comment: Actually, i need to get the memory usage of ignite server for every sometimes, and put the data into some file. How can i do this?

Comment: Just configure logging to be writed to file, it will contain this information automatically.
If you need more fine-grained solution, please check Ignite monitoring APIs.

Comment: can you give any reference for how to configure logging to be writing to file?

Comment: Please check https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/logging - but it does not cover configuring specific logging frameworks.

Comment: I'm not sure, I think it's too old and was never overhauled to support this.